# Echo title of PDF in Advanced Custom Fields, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, advanced-custom-fields

Anyone know how to replace the static label with the title of a PDF attachment in Advanced Custom Fields?

```
<?php if( get_field('other_reports') ): ?>

     <p><strong><a href="<?php the_field('other_reports'); ?>">Disclosure Reports</a></strong></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd like to replace "Disclosure Reports" with the PDF attachment's title property (e.g. 111 Main Street).

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set up the field. If you chose the "File Array" return value, you can use `get_field()` to get details beyond just the URL to the PDF. (Assuming you chose "File" as your field type.)

Here's an example for a field with the name `pdf_stuff`:

```
<?php
  while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $pdf = get_field( 'pdf_stuff' );
    $pdf_title = $pdf[ 'title' ]; // eg, "Balance_Sheet"
    $pdf_filename = $pdf[ 'filename' ]; // eg, "Balance_Sheet.pdf"
    $pdf_url = $pdf[ 'url' ]; // URL to file

  endwhile;
?>
```

You can see what's available by printing out the array to the screen:

```
<?php
  while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $pdf = get_field( 'pdf_stuff' );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $pdf );
    echo '</pre>';

  endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks very much for the response. I have chosen "File" as the field type, but I only see "File Object", "File URL", and "File ID" as options in the Return Value area. Maybe it's a Pro-level thing?

Comment: It could be a pro or newer version thing, but you should still try it with "File Object" and see what prints out. Use the second code I gave you to print out the File Object results and post here what prints to the screen. It should print out the full file object and then we can figure out what you need to grab.